# How to remove line from CSV file if entry matches an existing scheduled task name

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to cross-check a CSV log file that contain scheduled task details from tasks that we've created through another Powershell script. Sometimes we need to manually remove scheduled tasks so I would like a script that will check the CSV file against the existing scheduled tasks on the server and then output the CSV file back with the correct lines removed if a task doesn't exist with that particular name.

Currently I have this code but not sure why it is not working:

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\User\Logs\Files\Calendar-Permissions-Log.csv'
$Pattern = (Get-ScheduledTask).TaskName
(Import-Csv $SourceFile) | Where-Object {$Pattern -contains $_.'Task Name'} | Export-Csv $SourceFile
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm.
from what i gather from your explanation it works like it should.
it removes any entries that is in your original source file if there is no scheduled task for it.
BUT it does not add any so you are not aware if any new ones has been created.
If you would like to just overwrite the csv file with the current scheduled tasks you could simple do the following

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\temp\csv.csv'
$Pattern = (Get-ScheduledTask) | select-object TaskName | Export-Csv $SourceFile
```

and i am guessing you only want scheduled tasks from a specific directory so try this one

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\temp\csv.csv'
$Pattern = (Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \) | select-object TaskName | Export-Csv $SourceFile
```